# Automatically email Katalon test results from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, katalon-studio

I have, [thanks to this resource](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/jenskins-ci-integration/), successfully set up Katalon with Jenkins and was able to give demo of Jenkins running tests and generating graphical test reports on builds. Unfortunately, our team requires these results be explorable and sent automatically via email (or something similar). The developer of Test Results Analysis (the plugin I used from the demo) has [basically said there's no way to automatically send the graphical results via email](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=73532943&commentId=96076412#content/view/73532943/96076412).

Is there any way to fulfill this business requirement of ours?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way , You can generate an html file from the JUnit Report using https://pypi.org/project/junit2html/ 
Then send this html to the email using https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/